# Correct spelling mistake on help / closed-questions page: currenty => currently

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

The Help Center page [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)  appears to contain a spelling mistake for the description of the **unclear what you're asking** close reason. It reads (emphasis mine):

> Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to
>   highlight exactly what you need. The way the question is **currenty**
>   written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thus misspelling "currently". It should be corrected to read:

> Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to
>   highlight exactly what you need. The way the question is **currently**
>   written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.